# Oracle: filter all rows before the ID

Tags: sql, oracle, filtering

I have a big query that brings me a lot of rows, and based on each row I use this another query as a subselect.
This subselect brings me the following result rest on Oracle:

```
SELECT oc3.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA,
       oc3.ord,
       lag(oc3.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA, 1, NULL) OVER (
                                                     ORDER BY oc3.ord) ultimo
FROM
  ( SELECT DISTINCT oc2.*
   FROM
     ( SELECT oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA,
              oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA_PAI,
              oc1.SG_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA,
              rownum AS ord
      FROM TB_ORGAO_INTERNO oc1
      WHERE oc1.DH_EXCLUSAO IS NULL START WITH oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA =
           -- this is a value that come from an outer select
           -- If I put the value directly, like: S.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA, it does not work... I dont know why...
          (SELECT sa.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
           FROM TB_SOLICITACAO sa
           WHERE sa.ID_SOLICITACAO = 1077)-- s.ID_SOLICITACAO) 
 CONNECT BY
        PRIOR oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA_PAI = oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA) oc2
   INNER JOIN TB_PERMISSAO pe2_ ON pe2_.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA = oc2.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
   INNER JOIN TB_USUARIO u_ ON u_.ID_USUARIO = pe2_.ID_USUARIO
   WHERE pe2_.ID_STATUS_PERMISSAO = 7
     AND pe2_.ID_ATRIBUICAO IN :atribuicoes
   ORDER BY oc2.ord) oc3
```

The result:

[image]

That important value from each row is the `S.ID_SOLICITACAO`, because based on that value that the subquery will be started.

I need to be able to filter the results by `oc3.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA` where it brings me all the rows before that number.
So, If I filter by 430, only the row with 311 will return.
If I filter by 329, it will bring me the: 311 and 430.

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use your current query as a CTE, and then filter data it returns. Something like this:

```
with ycq as
  -- your current query
  (select ...
   from ...
  )
select *
from ycq a
where a.ord < (select b.ord
               from ycq b
               where b.id_orgao_inteligencia = :par_id_orgao_inteligencia
              );
```

Comment: I already tried something like that, not with the WITH clause, cause I'm in a subselect.
But when I use like that, It loses the reference (there's a comment in the query) from the outer query.  It only work when I put the value hardcoded

Comment: Doesn't matter; CTE is similar to a subquery (or an inline view). I don't quite understand what you are saying. If you created a table based on your select statement and applied query I posted to it, I guess you *should* get a correct result. So, why wouldn't you with a CTE/subquery as well?

Comment: I will try to explain better.

I have a big query that brings me a lot of rows, and for each row I have that subquery.
That subquery is based on the outer query value `S.ID_SOLICITACAO`.
I don't know why, but the `S.ID_SOLICITACAO` is not availble, or if it is it does not work, for the subquery. It only works if I put and hardcoded value, if comes from the outer query it does not work.